# Rails 3.1 Engine plugin rspec testing (external gem Spree Commerce)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, spree, rails-engines

I created an engine inside an app that depends on an external gem: Spree.
And I did my best to set RSpec within that engine following [this guide](http://rubyx.com/2011/03/01/start-your-engines).

When I try testing a controller with some integrated testing:
tests_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Tests" do
  describe "GET /tests" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
      get tests_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error in the dummy app's environment.rb file, that says that following command couldn't be run:

```
# Initialize the rails application
Dummy::Application.initialize!
```

Because my controller is using Admin::ResourceController as an extension which is declared within the external Spree gem. As if rspec is unable to read that class from gemfile of the main app (the one that contains the engine plugin).

Can someone please shed some light on that?

Comment: Hey, I recognise that guide! I wrote it. Could you outline how RSpec is unable to read that file?

Comment: Howdy, I solved the problem by reinstalling all my environment from scratch, I can't be more specific because I posted this a while ago....but yeah your name came up quite a lot in many of my Google searches :) 
Going a little off topic, I'm just curious about what you are up to lately, especially with todays gold rush in the tech industry combined with your skills, I guess you can achieve great things. ;)

Comment: I've just finished publishing my book and... well, it's a secret. Wait a month, you'll see.

Comment: Good luck! Makes me wonder where I wasted my free time in life, instead of actually doing something cool... like publishing a book!